# Nativescript Angular: How to pass a button view as a parameter in tap event ?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

My Nativescript Angular app dynamically returns data as a list of items. For each item, I use *ngFor to create a button with a tap event attached to it. I want to pass the button itself as a parameter as I need to add cssClass on tap. But I can't use ViewChild because the data is dynamic. How do I achieve this?

```
<Button *ngFor="let item of items" [text]="item.name" (tap)="select(item, buttonObject ? )></Button>


select(item, buttonObject) {
  let button = <View>buttonObject.nativeElement;
  ...
}
```

I appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For someone else looking for the same answer in the future, in addition to the solution provided by @HabibKazemi, in order to get every button in the parent view simply do the following:

```
select(button, item) {
  let parent = button.parent;
  let count = parent.getChildrenCount();
  for (var c = 0; c < count; c++) {
    let btn = parent.getChildAt(c);
    btn.color = "black";
  }
  button.color = "white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this can be done using  a local variable:

```
<Button #myButton *ngFor="let item of items"
     [text]="item.name" (tap)="select(item, myButton)></Button>


select(item, buttonObject) {
   let button = buttonObject;
}
```